# What is reason behind different keras layers initialization?

Tags: python, class, oop, keras, tf.keras

I have seen these type of layer initialization in keras

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

a = Input(shape=(32,))
b = Dense(32)(a)
c = Dense(b)
```

Its the initialization of c_th layer which is confusing. I have a class object like this

```
class Attention(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, features, hidden):
        hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)
        score = tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(features) + self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis))
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(self.V(score), axis=1)
        context_vector = attention_weights * features
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights
```

Look at `self.W1(features)` its taking the previous layer's feature and passing it to an already initialized weight `W1` dense layer with x `units` . What is happening in this step and why we are doing it?

EDIT:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, units):
        self.units=units
    def __call__(self):
        print ('called '+self.units)


a=Foo(3)
b=Foo(a)
```

why we need to call a function?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between initalizing and calling a layer.

`b = Dense(32)(a)` intializes a dense layer with 32 hidden units and then immediately calls this layer on the input `a`. For this you need to be aware of the concept of callable objects in Python; basically any object that has a `__call__` function defined (which the keras base `Layer` class does) can be called on an input, i.e. used like a function.

`c = Dense(b)` most certainly won't work, and if you have really seen this in a tutorial or piece of code somewhere, I would avoid that source in the future... This would attempt to create a layer with `b` units which makes no sense if `b` is the output of another dense layer. Most likely, whatever you saw was actually something like `c = Dense(n_units)(b)`.

That being said, all that happens in the `Attention` piece of code is that the layer `self.W1` is called on `features` (same for W2) after it had previously been initialized in `__init__`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer but I have some more doubts in calling a function. I  have added a simple class object in my previous question to simulate calling a function. Can you explain me what is the application of `call`?